# DKMI invalid using phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

i am using php mailer to send a Mail from my office mail adress.
When i send the message the DKIM Signature is invalid.

```
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = MAIL_HOST;                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = MAIL_USER;                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = MAIL_PASSWORD;                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = MAIL_PORT;                                    // TCP port to connect to
    $mail -> charSet = "UTF-8";

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom(MAIL_USER);
    $mail->addAddress('test-xxxxx@srv1.mail-tester.com', 'test-xxxx@srv1.mail-tester.com');     // Add a recipient

    // Attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'subject';
    
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    $mail->Body    = "My Content";

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

The message will send without any error but my DKIM is invalid.
I cant create a new dkmi private key, because my office not allow me to to it.

Why has the mail from mail outlook or outlook web mailer a valid dkmi signature?
i am using office365 from microsoft to sent my mail.

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: This code doesn't have any DKIM config? There are some DKIM bugs lurking in PHPMailer. I'm not sure where they are – it seems to work for some people and not others. Unfortunately DKIM is very difficult to diagnose. BTW, this is wrong: `$mail -> charSet = "UTF-8";`. It should be `$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";`; PHP is case sensitive for property names.

Comment: DKIM signatures are usually added by a gateway server - the server that communicates between the internal network and the public internet. If you're using Office 365 then a Microsoft server (or servers) somewhere is doing this for you. If you want some other machine to apply DKIM signatures then you'll need to configure it to do so. You'll need a private key (you won't get the ones that Microsoft use) and access to the DNS to set up the public key. PHPMailer supposedly will generate DKIM signatures, but if your company won't allow you to create a new private key you're stuck.